# Ruby-selenium connect to a remote webdriver

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I am using Ruby on GUI-less Ubuntu server. In order to run frontend tests with [chromdriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) (in headless mode) our system admin installed chrome on docker platform.

`docker run -p 3000:3000 -e "MAX_CONCURRENT_SESSIONS=10" -e "WORKSPACE_DELETE_EXPIRED=true" -e "WORKSPACE_EXPIRE_DAYS=7" --restart unless-stopped -d --name browserless browserless/chrome:latest`

I have an example on how to [connect to Chrome with Node.js](https://docs.browserless.io/docs/docker-quickstart.html#2-update-your-app-to-use-browserless) but I couldn't find such approach/gem for Ruby. Does anyone know how to make chromedriver to make use of the docker chrome instead of locally installed one?

** **EDIT** **

Here is what I tried:

```
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome("chromeOptions" => {"args" => [ "--headless", "--no-sandbox" ]})
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :remote, :url => "http://localhost:3000/webdriver", :desired_capabilities => caps
```

and I receive the following error:

> Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError:
>     unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
>       (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
>       (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

Comment: Check out [capybara](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara)

Comment: @jordanm

Thanks, that worked. After a day spent googling and reading this page  < https://docs.browserless.io/docs/capybara.html > saved me. It shows an example that worked to me at the first attempt. Just needed to tweak some configurations.